# How To: add dynamically HiddenField in masterpage base page

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, hidden, master-pages, radix

I have a Base MasterPage class, from which my masterpages will inherit. I have some javascript functions there for it's child pages to include. As it's a base class, it does not have a visual designer nor I can add XHTML code.
I need to add a hidden field to the class so I can set it's value in the javascript code, and when a postback occurs I can get the setted value on my content pages.
Yet I fail to achieve this, for when I try to add the hidden field to the base masterpage's control collection I get a render error (Content Encoding error if viewed in Firefox). And If I try cheating and registering a hidden field via scriptmanager with the same name in stead of adding the control to the control collection, well... I get the value as empty.
How could  achieve this?

Comment: Could u also post current implementation of what u want pls.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, but Tim's answer is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Public Class MyBaseMaster
    Inherits MasterPage

    Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
      If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
         Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("MyHiddenField1", "initialvalue")
      End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can access the HiddenField's value via `Request.Form("MyHiddenField1")` (since it's not a servercontrol, it isn't part of the page's control-collection).

[MSDN: HttpRequest.Form-Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx)

Comment: I have done this, and setted the value via javascript, but I couldn't figure out the way to get the value once I do the postback and running server side code. Is there a way? Please enlighten me!

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly! To think I spent like 6 hours until I decided to post my question...