# How to avoid Master Page hidden field value lost on new page load.

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a hidden field on master page. I am setting its value on a child page through JavaScript. When I click link on this child page it redirects to another page. Now I want to get the hidden field value on this new child page. But the value is lost(obviously). How can I persist this value.

Anyone help thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 good question / but can i suggest to set a session by ajax call instead of this scenario and use the session where ever you are , 
about ur hidden field i think the hidden field state is related to the page viewstate so every page have its own viewstate so the hiddenfield value will be flushed when ever you switch pages

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the value in the query string like this:

```
http://YourUrl.com/YourPage.aspx?YourValue=foo
```

Alternatively, you can initiate an AJAX call that stores the value in the session and then retrieve the value on the `page_load` event of the next page.

Comment: how to store the value in the session by ajax call..can u give me a code example. regards

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli, what server side language are you using? C# or VB?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the value to the link when ever you change it.

Or you can use ajax to send the new value to the server after the change.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic choices are to use javascript to either append it the link url as a querystring value or store it in a cookie.

Comment: yes cookie is a good idea...but how can i store html value in a cookie..basically i have a fckeditor and i want to store its value in the hidden field or cookie...how will i store this in the cookie..it only saves the first line...

Answer (score 0):

```
visit these links might be it helps you
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/219800/How-to-get-hidden-field-value-using-javascript-in-.aspx#answer3

[How To: add dynamically HiddenField in masterpage base page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935573/how-to-add-dynamically-hiddenfield-in-masterpage-base-page)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the page is redirect to another page, that means you must be using Response.Redirect or client side redirect. In this scenario you would not be to persist the hidden field value. To achieve this you might use a ajax call to save the value in a session variable and reload it on a appropriate master page event.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by handling the OnPageLoad event of your Master-page and assigning the value there too.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of defeats the purpose of master pages eh?  That was what the original intention was.

Answer (score 0):

use viewstate in the masterpage it works perfectly for this type of scenario

```
public string NavigateUrl
{
 get
  {
    string text = (string) ViewState["NavigateUrl"];
    if (text != null)
       return text;
    else
       return string.Empty;
  }
  set
  {
    ViewState["NavigateUrl"] = value;
  }
}
```